# How many zeros does $\sin(z)+2iz^2$ have inside $\{z:|\operatorname{Re}(z)| < \frac{\pi}{2}, |\operatorname{Im}(z)| \leq 1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How many zeros does $\sin(z)+2iz^2$ have inside $\{z:|\operatorname{Re}(z)|  < \frac{\pi}{2}, |\operatorname{Im}(z)| \leq 1\}$. Rouché's theorem does not apply here. Then I might want to write $\sin z = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$, since $|e^{iz}| = e^{-\operatorname{Im}z}$. What should be the next step?

Answer (score 0):

We can apply the [Symmetric version of Rouché's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem#Symmetric_version).
With the notations in the link, let
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(z) &= 2iz^2+\sin z
\\
&=z+2iz^2
-\frac 1{3!}z^3
+\frac 1{5!}z^5
-\frac 1{7!}z^7
+\frac 1{9!}z^9
-\frac 1{11!}z^{11}
+\frac 1{13!}z^{13}
-\frac 1{15!}z^{15}
+\dots
\ ,\\
g(z) &= 
z
+2iz^2
-\frac 1{3!}z^3
+\frac 1{5!}z^5
-\frac 1{7!}z^7
+\frac 1{9!}z^9
-\frac 1{11!}z^{11}
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and we have to show 
$$|f-g| \overset!< |f|+|g|$$ "on the boundary".

(This is my choice of $g$, always in such situations, sorry. It is not a "human choice", so that the following goes without computer interaction, but it is a "human friendly choice", since i will type less. More or less.)

The zeros of the polynomial $g$ even in the bigger disk of radius four around the origin are **exactly two**,

```
[0.000000000000000, 0.523118477244911*I]
```

as the following [sage](http://www.sagemath.org) dialog shows it.

```
sage: var('z');
sage: g = taylor( sin(z) + 2*i*z^2, z, 0 , 12 )
sage: g
-1/39916800*z^11 + 1/362880*z^9 - 1/5040*z^7 + 1/120*z^5 - 1/6*z^3 + 2*I*z^2 + z
sage: [ r for r in g.roots(ring=CC, multiplicities=False) if abs(r) < 4 ]
[0.000000000000000, 0.523118477244911*I]
sage: [ r for r in g.roots(ring=CC, multiplicities=False) if abs(r) < 5 ]
[0.000000000000000, 0.523118477244911*I, 4.30848033157392*I]
```

("Next root", the one with minimal absolute value bigger $4$ is `4.30848033157392*I`, all other roots come in pairs of conjugated roots not on the axes.)

(Using $g$ we detect the expected root in $0$, and a further root on the imaginary axis, this one with a good precision, one reason of going this way.)

One can also use Rouché's Theorem, showing that there are two zeros of $f$ inside the disk $B(0,1)$ (or radius $1$ centered in the origin), and also two inside the 
the disk $B(0,2)$.

---

**The domination:**
We consider a $z$ at the boundary of the ball / disk $B(0,r)$ of radius $r\in[1,2]$, centered in the origin. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
|f-g|(z)
&=  \left|
+\frac 1{13!}z^{13}
-\frac 1{15!}z^{15}
+\dots
\right|
\\
&\le \frac 1{13!}2^{13}
+\frac 1{15!}2^{15}
+\dots
\\
&\approx
0.000001340987\dots
\\
&\le 0.1\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The value comes with computer aid, pari/gp:

```
? suminf( n=6, 2^(2*n+1) / (2*n+1)! )
%1 = 1.3409879519086013549159421948457995574 E-6
? sinh(2) - sum( n=0, 5, 2^(2*n+1) / (2*n+1)! )
%2 = 1.3409879519086013549159421948458206587 E-6
```

And we estimate now the modulus of $g(z)$ in terms of (functions of) $r=|z|$, 
$$
\begin{aligned}
|g(z)|
&\ge
|2z^2|
-\left|z
+\frac{z^3}{3!}
+\frac{z^5}{5!}
+\frac{z^7}{7!}
+\frac{z^9}{9!}
+\frac{z^{11}}{11!}
\right|
\\
&\ge
2r^2
-\left[r
+\frac{r^3}{3!}
+\frac{r^5}{5!}
+\frac{r^7}{7!}
+\frac{r^9}{9!}
+\frac{r^{11}}{11!}
\right]
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
an increasing function of $r\in[1,2]$ starting from $0.824\dots>|f-g|(z)$. (Similarly, $|f(z)|\ge 2z^2-\sinh |z|$.)

So $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros, **two**, in each disk $B(0,r)$, $r\in[1,2]$, so also in the given rectangle, which lies in between in the inclusion $B(0,1)\subset B(0,2)$.

$\square$

---

The domination was shown, so $f$ has (as $g$) exactly two roots inside of any disk $B(0,r)$, for $r\in[1,2]$. We can calculate numerically the second zero of $f$, it is of the shape $it$ where $t$ is a real root of $\sinh t+2t^2$. Pari/GP code:

```
? solve( t=0.1, 1, sinh(-t) + 2*t^2 )
%10 = 0.52311847724494848572663138242373902647
? z = I * %10;
? sin(z) + 2*I*z^2
%12 = 2.938735877055718770 E-39*I
```

---

We can visualize the graph of $f$:

```
sage: var('z');
sage: complex_plot( lambda z: sin(z) + 2*i*z^2, (-pi/2, pi/2), (-1,1) )
Launched png viewer for Graphics object consisting of 1 graphics primitive
sage:
```

[image: Complex plot of $f(z)=\sin z+2i z^2$ in sage.]

The saturation of color gives the value in modulus, faded or intense colors. And starting from red in the color spectrum we have the arguments of values. 
Citing the sage documentation *The magnitude of the output is
   indicated by the brightness (with zero being black and infinity
   being white) while the argument is represented by the hue (with red
   being positive real, and increasing through orange, yellow, ... as
   the argument increases).*

The zero points have around them "many colors" (and should be black when zoomed). Some more zero values show when we look in a bigger square $[-20,20]^2$.

```
sage: complex_plot( lambda z: sin(z) + 2*i*z^2, (-20,20), (-20,20) )
Launched png viewer for Graphics object consisting of 1 graphics primitive
```

[image: Zeros of $f(z)=\sin z +2i z^2$ in a bigger domain.]

Note that $g$ (resp. each Taylor polynomial of $f$) has 
maximal growth in modulus on the negative imaginary axis, since for $r\in \Bbb R$, computing $g(-ri)$ we get
$$
g(-ri)=
-i\left(r+2r^2
+\frac{r^3}{3!}
+\frac{r^5}{5!}
+\frac{r^7}{7!}
+\frac{r^9}{9!}
+\frac{r^{11}}{11!}
\right)\ ,
$$
so its modulus is the modulus of the part in the parenthesis, which is $r+2r^2+\dots$.